# How to save a variable permanently?

Tags: jquery

I have a website where people click a button and a counter moves up each time.  I want the variable to be permanent so I can log how many times the button has been clicked by anyone from any computer.  I know of the `localStorage` but I want it to change across computers.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.yes').click(function() {
        $('#green').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
    }); 
    $('.no').click(function() {
        $('#red').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Then you need to store it in your back end. Front end that is not possible.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use Google Analytics. Requires no server side coding. Just attach an event to the button and let GA track. You'll also get much more than just number of clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Store the number inside of a database and have the button update the number

Comment: That's what I was thinking, how would I do that?

Comment: This will be a very broad answer. If you like I can update my answer but I don't know how much depth I can go into. It might be best to start a chat room and communicate via there?

Comment: Do you know where to start a chat room? I really appreciate any and all the help you've given me.  My number is 918-906-5253, where I'll be quick to respond.

Answer (score 0):

If it is on the same machine then **cookies** might be the only way.
 `LocalStorage` could also be used but not all versions of all browsers support that. eg. if the user uses IE7  browser, it will not work. But it cannot be updated across computers.
If you want to track it across computers, no matter where the user logs in, like the Facebook *like* button, then it has to be on  a database, which might not be possible with just javascript. You might need some server side programming language like php, java.

Comment: How would I use that to update everytime I click? and not just everytime the website loads